# Sum over subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's say I have three sets $P$, $Q$ and $S\subset P$ and variables $x_{qs}$ with $q\in Q$ and $s\in S$.

From a purely formal point of view: Is it then wrong to say $\sum_{s\in P}x_{qs} \quad\forall q\in Q$?

Pro: $P$ is a superset of $S$. So simply all existing variables will be summed up for every $Q$.

Con: Because only some elements of $P$ have a corresponding variable $x_{qs}$, it raises something like an index error.

Comment: $\sum_{s\in P}x_{qs}$ looks meaningless, because the variable $x_{qs}$ does not exist for $s\in P\setminus S$. So I go with your Con argument, even without the "for all  q".

Comment: Look at it another way. Suppose I define $x_n$ to be the $n$th prime and then ask you to find $\sum_{i\in\mathbb{R}} x_i$. That is clearly silly.

Comment: I see your point. Let's think of $x_{qs}$ as a sparse matrix. Then we have tuples of $(q,s)$. How would I write a sum notation then? $\sum_{s:(q,s)\in X}x_{qs}\quad\forall q:(q,s)\in X$